# Multiple Locale Resolver in Spring.

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Is it possible to have multiple locale resolver inside spring ?

I want to have multiple Locale Resolver inside my application like :

1. CookieLocaleResolver for user permanent language.
2. Http request Based LocaleResolver for just seeing a particular
       page in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see problem to write your own `LocaleResolver` and register it as bean with name `DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME`.

The logic of `resolveLocale` implementation may be really based on the `request`, when you can determine to use `CookieLocaleResolver` or provide someother locale from `request` attributes

Comment: Yeah man i understood it, there's an interface called LocalResolver and if my class implements it, I can get the HttpServletRequest from its method called resolveLocale and put a condition in there and solve the problem ! thanx man .